# Is there a significant named political movement in the United States for Latino civil rights?

Tags: united-states, immigration, protests

I am aware of movements like Black Lives Matter, LGBTQ+ Pride, and the Women's March that stand for the civil rights of different groups.

Is there such a movement or organization that organizes for Hispanic and Latino civil rights in the United States?

I'm hoping to find such a movement that, like the ones I listed, has a name that most, or at least many, Americans will recognize offhand and understand what it stands for.

Comment: *Latino* is a much broader group than the two examples you gave.  Also, they sway across the political spectrum a good amount, giving about 1/3 to the right and 2/3 to the left. That makes it pretty hard for any legitimate movement to form around them specifically. This is for American politics. It may be quite different south of the border, idk.

Comment: I think UnidosUS, formerly La Raza (The Race), does something like this.

Answer (score 2):

One such organization is [**LULAC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_United_Latin_American_Citizens) (pronounced `ˈlulæk`), the League of United Latin American Citizens, founded in 1929.

From the LULAC website:

> The League of United Latin American Citizens is the largest and oldest Hispanic membership organization in the United States. LULAC is a volunteer-based organization that empowers Latinos and builds strong Latino communities.

On their [advocacy](https://lulac.org/advocacy/) page, LULAC states:

> The mission of the League of United Latin American Citizens is to advance the economic condition, educational attainment, political influence, housing, health and civil rights of the Hispanic population of the United States.

LULAC concentrates on civic participation, civil rights, education, housing, advocacy and other related topics.

Another organization is [**MALDEF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_American_Legal_Defense_and_Educational_Fund) (pronounced `ˈmældɛf`), the Mexican American Legal Defense and Educational Fund, founded in 1968.

MALDEF [claims](https://www.maldef.org/) to be "the nation’s leading Latino legal civil rights organization" and is committed "to protect and defend the rights of all Latinos living in the United States and the constitutional rights of all Americans."

Whereas LULAC accomplishes its goals through programming, advocacy, and membership, MALDEF works through the justice/courts/legal system.